# Identify this partly-built clone brand plane

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

Someone offered my  kid a big box of mixed LEGO parts. I tried to identify some sets and I managed to build 60139 and a monster truck from Technic. But now I'm stuck. I cannot find another set (and I have around 3.5 kg more to work with)

Does anyone know which sets are these partially build parts?

I added some pictures. Looks like the wing and and the plane are related I think.

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]
[image: Pic3]
[image: Pic4]

Comment: I see no "lego" markings on the studs, so this must be from a clone brand.

Comment: The stickers on the first two pictures are placed in ways LEGO wouldn't do,  further indicating that this is from a clone brand.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity This is true for recent sets, but LEGO used to have stickers across multiple parts (aka STAMP). Dismissing the fact that pictured set is from clone brand, it is plausible that older set could have had STAMP.

Comment: I wasn't as much talking about them being across multiple parts, as them being on studs (in the second picture). And all the STAMPs I've seen in LEGO sets have at least been fairly flat, not like the one in the first picture being on both the sloped and vertical parts of those pieces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are Ausini

The red / gray assembly is from
[image: ausini 25468]

The white parts are from

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I lost 6 hours trying to find something wrong. All other sets are from lego, i didn t imagine it had some outsiders.